# Toolbar not showing menu when minsdk set to 21 or lollipop 5.0

Tags: android-toolbar, android-menu

I am testing toolbar in Android 5.0 lollipop to show menu where my configurations are min sdk 21 and target sdk 23 I am using default toolbar from sdk 21 i.e Android 5.0 lollipop not using Appcompact v7 to support earlier version than Android 5.0 lollipop but I am stuck at menu which is not showing always I tried lots of but no luck.please get me rid of that.

following is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

          TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.text);
          mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#636161"));
          mTitle.setTextSize(25);

          toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
          toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eea9b8"));
          toolbar.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refresh App",       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_new) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to pass your custom toolbar to `setActionBar(toolbar);` method.

Try adding the above code statement at the end of `OnCreate` function. If that doesn't work then make the following changes.

`styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

I've made a sample code in github look at it -> [Link](https://github.com/Protino/TestProject)

Comment: i think you have not got my question i am not using appcompact v7 i have used default toolbar from sdk 21 api i.e Android 5.0  i am extend Activity not AppcompactActivity so setsupportActionbar (toolbar) will not be resolved. where min sdk 21 and target sdk 23.

Comment: Oh sorry I got it now. Actually setAction(toolbar) will be resolved even if you extend from Activity. I've tried this and got correct results.

Comment: @Viral make sure you import toolbar from `android.widget.toolbar` and even in layout files it should be `android.widget.toolbar`.

Comment: thanks dear. setActionbar(toolbar) has solved my issue.